# Dominion card game - how can I take advantage of interfaces?

Tags: c++, beginner, game, playing-cards

I'm writing a card game (Dominion) as a pet project. I'm new to C++ but not programming.

A player has a deck, containing the hand and cards in play (tableau). Outside the player, there are piles of cards to buy from (supply piles). I want to display these objects (the hand, tableau and supply piles) on the screen. I had chosen to represent the hand and tableau using `std::vector<Card>` and the supply piles as `std::vector<SupplyPile>`. `Card` and `SupplyPile` implement an interface for displaying contents to the screen

```
class IInfo {
public:
  virtual std::string Info() const = 0;
  virtual std::string ToString() const = 0;
};
```

I have a class I'm calling `View` that will take on displaying things to the screen.

```
class View {
public:
  View(const std::vector<IInfo*>& items, int window_starty, int window_startx);
  virtual ~View() { }

  const IInfo& CurrentItem() const;
  const int CurrentIndex() const;
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  void ItemDown();
  void ItemUp();
  void SetActive();
  void SetInactive();
  virtual void Update();
protected:
  virtual WINDOW* InitializeWindow(int lines,
    int cols,
    int starty,
    int startx);

  virtual ITEM** MakeMenuItems();
private:
  // Some constants

  const std::vector<IInfo*>& items_;

  MENU *menu_;
  WINDOW *window_;
};
```

I now know that C++ doesn't support covariance in templates, so I can't create instances of `View` with the supply pile, hand, and tableau. How can I redesign the system to maximize DRY? The `View` class operates on its container member in a very simple way, ripe for abstraction.

### Examples of things I want to do

```
std::vector<Card> hand = player.hand();
std::vector<Card> tableau = player.tableau();
std::vector<SupplyPile> supply_piles = game.supply_piles();

View hand_view = new View(hand, starty, startx);
View tableau_view = new View(tableau, starty, startx);
View supply_piles_view = new View(supply_piles, starty, startx);
```

One answer suggested making `View` into a template, and it almost worked until I remembered that I want to track which `View` is active at a given time:

```
View active_ = hand_view;
// Later
active_ = supply_piles_view;
```

I can't do this with `View<Card>` and `View<SupplyPile>`.

### Other code

```
class Card : public IInfo {
public:
  Card(std::string name,
    int cost,
    int initial_supply,
    std::string text,
    std::string type);
  ~Card();

  void Play();
  std::string Info() const;
  std::string ToString() const;

  int cost() const;
  int initial_supply() const;
  std::string name() const;
  std::string text() const;
private:
  int cost_;
  int initial_supply_;

  std::string name_;
  std::string text_;
  std::string type_;

  std::string set_;
};

class SupplyPile : public IInfo {

public:
    SupplyPile(const Card& card, int initial_count);
    SupplyPile(const SupplyPile& other);
    virtual ~SupplyPile();
    virtual bool operator==(const SupplyPile& other) const;

    bool BuyOrGain();
    std::string Info() const;
    std::string ToString() const;

    const Card& card() const;
    int count() const;
    std::string name() const;
private:
    const Card& card_;

    int count_;
};
```

Comment: Your question isn't fully clear to me. If you create a `std::vector<IInfo*> x;` then you can do `push_back(new Card(...)`, `push_back(new SupplyPile(...))`. Templates aren't covariant, no, so if you have `template <typename T> class Foo` then `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` are totally separate types for any `A` and `B` (even if B derives from A), but I don't see where that's an issue in any of your code.

Comment: Updated with a snippet of code I wanted to write but can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something I don't much like, but it works.

I redesigned `View` to work with disposable copies of a new interface, `IViewable`. `IViewable` will be the link between the UI and the core logic. Every time a UI update is needed, copies of the items to display will be passed as `std::vector<IViewable*>`.

The new `View` ctor is:

```
  View(std::vector<IViewable*> *initial_items, int window_starty, int window_startx)
```

Updates need a new set of items to display each time, rather than using a reference to the originals like I wanted:

```
  void Update(std::vector<IViewable*> *items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why `View` itself can't be a template?

```
template <typename T> class View {
public:
  View(const std::vector<T>& items, int window_starty, int window_startx);
  virtual ~View() { }

  const T& CurrentItem() const;
  // ...
  const std::vector<T>& items_;
  // ...
};

View<Card> hand_view = new View<Card>(hand, starty, startx);
```

Comment: This had occurred to me, but I'm not sure if it will work. There is one method that needs to call `ToString()` on an element of `items_`. If I can do that, then I should be able to convert to a template. Perhaps a cast is in order?

Comment: Not a problem. `items_[0].ToString()` _etc_ will work fine.

Comment: Still not there. I edited the original question to explain the new problem: I want to be able to track which `View` is active at a given moment.

Comment: You could derive `View<T>` from a base class/ interface, so you could maintain a reference to that instead. Or even just have an enumerated constant to represent it. At this point though, you're straying even further from the site remit...